# why can't i insert new values into my combined primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

i would like to insert values into my combined primary key. However, i only get the erorr message **Duplicate entry '1-16' for key 'PRIMARY'**
I am sure there is no connection problems as previous SELECT querys have worked, and everything else on the site is running. Below is my code for the segmet. I am very grateful for all help, but as i am a beginner i would really apreciate straightfoward and easy answers:) Thanks in advance!

```
<form  method="post">
<select  name="sport_id">
  <?php
$sql= "SELECT * FROM sport";
 $resultat= $kobling->query($sql);
 while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
   $sport_id=$rad["sport_id"];
   $sportName=$rad["name"];

   echo "<option value='$sport_id'> $sportName </option>";
 }
   ?>
</select>

<select name="person_id">
  <?php
$sql= "SELECT person_id, fname, lname FROM person";

$resultat= $kobling->query($sql);
while ($rad= $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
  $person_id=$rad["person_id"];
  $fname= $rad["fname"];
  $lname =$rad["lname"];
  $navn= $fname. " ". $lname;
  echo "<option value='$person_id'> $navn </option>";
  // code...
}
 ?>
</select>

Året du startet:
<input type="number" name="startyear" value="">

<input type="submit" name="leggtil3" value="Legg til">

</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["leggtil3"])) {
  $person_id=$_POST["person_id"];
  $sport_id = $_POST["sport_id"];
  $startyear=$_POST["startyear"];

$sql= "INSERT INTO personsport (sport_id, person_id, startyear) values ('$sport_id', '$person_id', '$startyear')";
if ($kobling->query($sql)) {
echo "koblingen $sql ble gjennomført";
}
else {
  echo "det var et problem med $sql ($kobling->error)";
}
}

 ?>
```

[image: here is a picture of my datamodel]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. what are you actually using? I've removed the conflicting tags. please retag the RDBMS you are actually using, and **only** that RDBMS. Thanks.

Comment: is there also a way to delete identical rows, so you only get unique rows?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` is attempting to assign a non-unique combination for `PRIMARY` fields. `Auto Increment` can mess up; ensure the next number in sequence is not taken.

[Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

> Updating an existing AUTO_INCREMENT column value in an InnoDB table
>   does not reset the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence as it does for MyISAM and
>   NDB tables.

(It looks like your just entering the same person and sport twice. Those fields must be unique in combination due to your index.)

Answer (score 0):

The primary keys 1 - 16 are already assigned in the database. Check the database to be sure your next value for auto increment does not hold any of these values.